# compare range of value with another range of values MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like as below

```
id_indicator    id_threshold    activation_begin_value  activation_end_value

    1           121                    1                       2
    1           122                    3                       4
    1           123                    5                       6
    1           124                    6                       7 
    2           125                    10                      9
    2           126                    8                       7
    2           127                    6                       5
    2           128                    5                       4
```

how can I get the details where  activation_begin_value and activation_end_value value fall in to another threshold. where 6 fall into id_threshold 123 and 124 same as following two rows where 5 in two id_threshold. query output like as follow

```
id_indicator     id_threshold     activation_begin_value     activation_end_value

    1           123                    5                       6
    1           124                    6                       7 
    2           127                    6                       5
    2           128                    5                       4
```

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: I just want to find out where value fall into tow thresold

Comment: I refer you to my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like.

```
Select a.id_indicator     a.id_threshold     a.activation_begin_value     a.activation_end_value from table a
where 1=1 
and a.activation_begin_value in ( select activation_end_value from table )
union 
Select b.id_indicator     b.id_threshold     b.activation_begin_value     b.activation_end_value from table b
where 1=1 
and b.activation_end_value in ( select activation_begin_value from table )
```

Comment: not giving me the out put I am looking for, Each indicator has 4 difference threshold and I need to find specific indicator threshold value not fall into difference threshold value, It could be group by indicator

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me this is possible with an self join and some sorting. 
Mine result is the same you want.

**Test data**

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`id_indicator` INT, `id_threshold` INT, `activation_begin_value` INT, `activation_end_value` INT)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (`id_indicator`, `id_threshold`, `activation_begin_value`, `activation_end_value`)
VALUES
    (1, 121, 1, 2),
    (1, 122, 3, 4),
    (1, 123, 5, 6),
    (1, 124, 6, 7),
    (2, 125, 10, 9),
    (2, 126, 8, 7),
    (2, 127, 6, 5),
    (2, 128, 5, 4)
;
```

**Query**

```
SELECT 
   table1.id_indicator
 , table1.id_threshold
 , table1.activation_begin_value 
 , table1.activation_end_value 
FROM 
 Table1 table1
INNER JOIN
 Table1 table12
ON
 table1.activation_begin_value = table12.activation_end_value
ORDER BY 
    table1.id_indicator ASC
  , table1.id_threshold ASC
```

**Result**

```
id_indicator  id_threshold  activation_begin_value  activation_end_value  
------------  ------------  ----------------------  ----------------------
           1           123                       5                       6
           1           124                       6                       7
           2           127                       6                       5
           2           128                       5                       4
```

See demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d18f2/2

Comment: sorry I am little bit confuse, did you use 4 table

Comment: My table name is threshold, do i have to use code like FROM threshold 1, threshold 2 Inner Join threshold 3, threshold 4

Comment: Not giving me the answer like yours